# How can I by default display decimal numbers in Ionic/Angular app in correct locale number format?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, format

I work on an Ionic/Angular app that often needs to display decimal numbers on its pages. I have set LOCALE_ID in my app to be "cs". Therefore, I would expect that numbers will be displayed by using this locale. So, "1,000.23" should display as "1 000,23". But this is not the case.

I know that I can use DecimalPipe to set correct format on individual variables. But that would mean I would need to do it on every number I need to display. If possible, I would like to avoid that.

Here is what I did when trying to solve the problem.
In `angular.json` file I set these settings:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "cs"
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "localize": true,
          }
```

In `app.module.ts` I have added these rows:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import localeCs from '@angular/common/locales/cs';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';


registerLocaleData(localeCs);

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'cs' },
  ],
})
```

Now, as an example, I have these variables in one of my TS modules:

```
let float1=1501.321
let float2=34.42
let float3=2535478.9
```

I would display the numbers in corresponding HTML page in this way.

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-label> {{ float1 }} </ion-label>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
  <ion-label> {{ float2 }} </ion-label>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
  <ion-label> {{ float3 }} </ion-label>
</ion-row>
```

I want them displayed like this:

```
1 501,321
34,42
2 535 478,9
```

But for now, the only way I can achieve this is using pipe, like this:

```
<ion-label> {{ floatX | number:'1.0-3' }} </ion-label>
```

Is there a way how can I achieve correct number format by default? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another parameter to number pipe like below!

html

```
<label> {{ float1 | number: '1.0-3':localeId }} </label><br /><label>
  {{ float2 | number: '1.0-3':localeId }} </label
><br /><label> {{ float3 | number: '1.0-3':localeId }} </label>

<br />
locale id: {{ localeId }}
```

ts

```
import { Component, Injector, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  float1 = 1501.321;
  float2 = 34.42;
  float3 = 2535478.9;
  localeId: string;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.localeId = this.injector.get(LOCALE_ID);
  }
}
```

app.module

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import localeCs from '@angular/common/locales/cs';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(localeCs);

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'cs' }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hubj8k)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate time you spent when designing a solution. But it seems this is not what I was looking for. You suggested to add another parameter to pipe. What I am looking for is to omit pipe altogether while having the number displayed in the correct format. In other words, display number in a default localized format even when no pipe is defined. I am not sure whether this is even possible.